# Issue with huge CrossJoin - Improving a Query

Tags: mdx

i got a query that consists of a  cross join between 3 dims .

dim1- has 15,000 members

dim2- this is the organisation hierarchy

dim 3- has 30,000 members

this is the query:

```
TOPCOUNT(

      FILTER(
      (NONEMPTY([DIM1].[Key].[All],[Measures].[Target])
      *DIM2.CHILDREN*
      NONEMPTY([DIM3].[Key].[All],[Measures].[Target])),
      [Measures].[Target]>0
             ),20,[Measures].[Gap)
```

as you can imagine -this is a huge cross join but i have to do this ...

i tried functions like "filter" and "non empty" but it doesnt help...it takes more then 30 minutes...

how can i improve it so it will run in a short time?

thank you

Comment: Which Software are you using? Analysis Services? Mondrian? Essbase? Which version? All this is relevant information for the optimization.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that `[DIM1].[Key].[All]` and `[DIM3].[Key].[All]` just shows the `All` element and nothing else?